# Bootstrap Text One on top of the other in navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a profile button in bootstrap.

It should be showing Name on top, user type below that and the Caret on the right Basically the standard bootstrap text with caret dropdown but with a second line of text.
As you can see from the jsfiddle, the caret ends up below both texts.

What do I need to change to make the caret stay to the right of both?

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <div>Joe Shmo 

      <div style="font-size: 10px;">
        SUPERUSER
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/profile"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Edit Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/password-change"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Change Password</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/logout/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5v35ezfc/1/

Comment: witch bootstrap version  for used this ?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/5v35ezfc/3/

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with the below

```html
<div>
  Joe Mallanga <span class="caret"></span>
  <div style="font-size: 10px;">
    SUPERUSER
  </div>
</div>
```